# Using an IF in an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the score for a particular user, only if the number of articles added by him are `>=10`.

How can I add the part which checks if his artcAdded is `>=10`?

In pseudocode, this would be;

```
update tableScores, set score = 'Good' where userId = 1 (if artcAdded for userId = 1 is >= 10) 
// Calcualate and update the score only if his artcAdded is >= 10
```

I presently do this `update tableScores set score = 'Good' where userId = 1 and artcAdded >=10;` This works, but is this the right way to do it? Should I be using an IF clause?

**Unprocessed Table**

```
"userId"    "artcAdded" "artcApproved"  "artcRejected"  "score"
"1"         "10"        "7"             "3"             NULL
"2"         "5"         "4"             "1"             NULL
"3"         "3"         "1"             "2"             NULL
```

**After processing**

```
"userId"    "artcAdded" "artcApproved"  "artcRejected"  "score"
"1"         "10"        "7"             "3"             Good
"2"         "5"         "4"             "1"             NULL
"3"         "3"         "1"             "2"             NULL
```

Comment: It's OK if you only want to update score with `'Good'`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a simple `and` statement

```
update tableScores, set score = 'Good' where userId = 1 and artcAdded >= 10
```

Comment: Which is what I do. But I thought this was a bit primative, so I decided to add the IF and got stuck.

Comment: Surely your know about KISS

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableScores, set score = 'Good' where userId = 1 
AND artcAdded >= 10
```

Adding an AND clause is the right way for this. `IF CLAUSE` would be helpful when you want to update column with different values based on certain criteria.

For e.g. Updated score to "Good" if artcAdded >= 10 else update it to "Bad"

Comment: Which is exactly what I do.

Comment: You can explain why this is the right solution for a better answer.